# Why is inner join with or condition lead to ALL select type?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `users` with columns `(id,name,company_id)` and `companies` with columns `(id,name)`. The `id` columns are primary keys. Also I have `(company_id,name)` indexed in the `users` table and `(id,name)` indexed in the `companies table`.

I have this query to join them:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
        INNER JOIN
    `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id`
WHERE
    `name` = 'bill'
        OR companies.name = 'rose'
```

To my surprise, this causes a full ALL scan over all users. How is this possible?
Should this query not use the index `(company_id,name)` on the users table and the index `(id,name)` on the companies table?

[image]

Here are the create statments

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  KEY `users_company_id_first_name_index` (`company_id`,`name`),
   KEY `users_first_name_index` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `companies_name_id_index` (`name`,`id`),
  KEY `companies_name_index` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Try only selecting the columns you need instead of the anti-pattern of using `SELECT *`. If those columns are covered by the index, you should be in good shape. In addition to that, if you re-write your query to something logically equivalent that eliminates the `OR` operator in your `WHERE` clause, for example: `SELECT OnlyTheFieldsYouNeed FROM users INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = users.company_id WHERE name = 'bill' UNION SELECT OnlyTheFieldsYouNeed FROM users INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = users.company_id WHERE name = 'rose'` does that use your index as expected?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables; I worry that some details got lost.

Comment: @J.D. if I select only columns that are in the index then the rows are read by type index, so he doesn't need to fetch the entries, but he still has to go over all rows.

Comment: @RickJames added those statements to the question.

Comment: @Adam You would need to employ both changes I suggested for optimal querying. It seems like you've done that by following RickJames's answer that goes into a little more detail on what I said about the `OR` operator. The problem with using `OR` is it's not exactly SARGable, so it's not always easy for the SQL engine to utilize an index seek on it. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099633/5059085) has more information (especially the link to Grant Fritchey) about it. (Despite that being an answer to SQL Server, the same concept applies to other database systems equally.)

Comment: @Adam - "then the rows are read by type index" -- That means that it is only looking in the INDEX's BTree, not the data's BTree.  It fails to point out that it is scanning the entire index, which is nearly as costly as scanning all the data.  (cf "Covering index")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` effectively forces the query to find all combinations of companies and users, then filter through the mess.  `OR` is usually slow; the `JOIN` simply aggravates it.  *No* index will solve the problem.

Use `UNION` instead of `OR`:

```
( SELECT * FROM users AS u JOIN companies AS c ON c.id = u.company_id
      WHERE u.name = 'bill' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM users AS u JOIN companies AS c ON c.id = u.company_id
      WHERE c.name = 'rose' )
```

With these indexes:

```
companies:  (name)
users:  (company_id)
```

Comment: Can you recommend a book that goes deeper into this topic as why the `OR` forces the query to find all combinations? In my imagination, I don't see why joining two tables makes the other indexes unusable.

Comment: @Adam - My blog ( http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql ) has some discussion.  It might be best to discuss specific examples.

Comment: The _main_ criteria for performance is how many "rows" (of index and/or data) it has to fetch.  MySQL rarely turns `OR` into multiple, easily-optimizable, queries to join via `UNION`.  I discuss an example here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1